# vue.js 3 tabs in a 1 tab

Tags: vue.js, tabs, components

I have 3 tabs in 1st level, and i want to add more tabs in 2nd tab. I created a vue component Index.vue and added 3 tabs. It works. But when I added 3 more tabs from ArmorTams.vue it doesn't work.

[result of work: codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-y5d8d)

**Index.vue**

```
<template>
<v-app>
    <v-tabs grow v-model="active_tab">
        <v-tab
                v-for="tab of tabs"
                :key="tab.index"
                :title="tab"
        >
            {{tab.name}}
        </v-tab>
        <v-tab-item v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
            {{tab.content}}
        </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
</v-app>
```

```
<script>
    import ArmorTabs from "components/helper/ArmorTabs.vue"

    export default {
        components:{
            ArmorTabs
        },
        data: () => ({
            active_tab: 1,
            tabs: [
                { index: 0, name: 'MAIN', content: "123" },
                { index: 1, name: 'ARMORS', content: ArmorTabs },
                { index: 2, name: 'WEAPONS', content: "789"  }
            ]
        })
    }
</script>
```

**ArmorTabs.vue** is a same. And I try to add in content: ArmorTabs

```
<template>
<v-app>
    <v-tabs grow v-model="active_tab">
        <v-tab
                v-for="tab of tabs"
                :key="tab.index"
        >
            {{tab.name}}
        </v-tab>
        <v-tab-item v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
            {{tab.content}}
        </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
</v-app>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            tabs: [
                { index: 5, name: 'MAIN', content: "123" },
                { index: 6, name: 'ARMORS', content: "456"  },
                { index: 7, name: 'WEAPONS', content: "789"  }
            ]
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io (or similar) if you find it difficult to reproduce on [so].

Comment: My apologize, I added. Should I delete examples of code?

Comment: The codesandbox you added doesn't work. Make sure each file is saved. Best way to check is to open it in an incognito window. And no, you shouldn't delete the code samples, as they are relevant to your question (it needs to make sense even without codesandbox).

Comment: link to codesandbox was repaired

Answer (score 0):

There's no `active_tab` defined in your ArmorTabs.vue component.

One more thing: don't use arrow functions on Vue's instance properties.

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                active_tab: 5, // ------ add this
                tabs: [
                    { index: 5, name: 'MAIN', content: "123" },
                    { index: 6, name: 'ARMORS', content: "456"  },
                    { index: 7, name: 'WEAPONS', content: "789"  }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. i think, that i added wrong this section in index.vue `{ index: 1, name: 'ARMORS', content: ArmorTabs }`

Answer (score 0):

it helps

```
<v-tab-item v-for="(tab, name) in tabs" :key="name">
    <div v-if='tab.name == "ARMORS"'>
        <ArmorTabs/>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        {{ tab.content }}
    </div>
</v-tab-item>
```